# My Google Play App say "Insufficient space" when everyone try to install it

Tags: android, google-play, diskspace

the link of my app is:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pensoft.guesstheimage

The problmes is that every one that want to install it alway say "Insuficcient space".

I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: how many space in your internal memory ?